# Implementing a Queue using Structured programming

Tags: arrays, pointers, queue, structure

I'm new to C so our class is starting out by using structured programming.  In terms of the # of parameters everything is fine, but I'm having a hard time understanding the error message. When trying to call enqueue and dequeue it says that and int cannot be converted to an int*. I'm just having a hard time understanding pointers when it comes to structured programming and passing values and addresses.

```
bool Enqueque(int queue[], int* front, int* rear, int intialSize);
int Dequeque(int queue[], int* front, int* rear);
int GetCurrentSize(int queue[], int* front, int* rear);
int toString(int queue[], int* front, int* rear);

int main()
{
    bool enqueueResult, dequeueResult, ifEmpty;
    int UserOption = 0;  
    int initialSize = 10;

    int* queue = (int*)malloc( initialSize * sizeof(int) );
    for(int i = 0; i<initialSize; i++)
        queue[i] = 0;

    int* front, rear;


    printf("This program implements Queues using structured programming. Enter "
            "a number from 1 to 4 . \n"
            "1. To enqueue a number \n"
            "2. To dequeue a number \n"
            "3. To get the current size of the queue \n"
            "4. To see the contents within the queue \n");
    scanf( "%d",UserOption );

    switch(UserOption)
    {
        case 1:
            enqueueResult = Enqueque(queue, front, rear, initialSize);

            if(enqueueResult == true)
                printf( "The number has been put into the queue!");
            else
                printf("The number was not able to be enqueued!");
            break;

        case 2:
            dequeueResult = Dequeque( queue, front, rear );

            if(dequeueResult == true)
                printf( "The number has been dequeued!");
            else
                printf("The number wasn't able to be dequeued!");
            break;

        case 3:
            printf( "The current size of the queue is: " + GetCurrentSize( queue, front, rear) );
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future comments, please add the complete error messages and warnings of your compiler. However, I think the problem is your `scanf()`

You wrote:

```
scanf( "%d",UserOption );
```

`scanf()` needs the address of a variable as a parameter.
Therfore, you need to write:

```
scanf( "%d",&UserOption );
```

That's why you get the error message. It expects a pointer to an integer (in order to modify the value of UserOption from within scanf()) but you pass UserOption to scanf(). What you are doing is called *Pass-by-Value* but scanf() needs a *Pass-By-Reference*. Since you are new to C here a quick explanation of both principles:

**Pass-by-Value:**
The function you are calling receives a copy of your passed parameter.

```
int foo(int bar){
  ...
}

int main(void){
  int x = 5;
  foo(x);
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

When foo() is called a copy of the variable x is passed to foo. This means that the function variable bar is initialized with the content of x, hence 5.

**Pass-by-reference**:
The function you are calling receives the address of a variable. Pointers are used to save an address in C. Therefore, in the function definition bar is not declared as a pointer to an int (int*) and called with the address of x (&x).

```
int foo(int* bar){
  ...
}

int main(void){
  int x = 5;
  foo(&x);
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

When foo() is called a copy of the address of variable x is passed to foo. This means that the function pointer bar is initialized with the address of x. The content of bar is now an address. Pass-by-reference is used to access non-function variables from with a function. It also enhances performance since you don't need to make a dedicated copy of your parameter.